# How Do I iterate through nested properties of Json in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loops, iteration

I have a json object with three level of nesting I have to Iterate it Dynamically

Here is my code

```
var responseObj ={ 
           db_config:{
             db_user: 'das1234',
            },
           env_con:{
             db_con:'ds67'
           },
           db_password: 'ds345ty76',
           db_host: 'wdsa12'
          }    


        function decrypt(responseObj,key){  
            var list = []
            //get the keys from the responseObj 
            Object.keys(responseObj).forEach(function(key){
                    //Push the keys into a list
                    list.push(key);
                })
            console.log(list)

            try{
                for(var i =0;i<list.length;i++){
                    //Decrypt the values of the key
                    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key);
                    //Assign The decrypted value to the keys
                    responseObj[list[i]] = decipher.update(responseObj[list[i]], 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8')
                }
                return responseObj;

            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }   
        }  


    var res = decrypt(responseObj,key)
    console.log(res)
```

had tried lot ways I just confused How to get the keys and values as iterated dynamically without using the key as static.
Have any Idea about pls help to find it out.

Comment: *"How Do I iterate through nested properties of Json in nodejs?"* You don't. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange.(http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. [(More.)] You can loop through the nested properties of the object tree you get when you *parse* it, though, at which point you're not dealing with JSON anymore. But there's no JSON at all in the question, so no need for parsing.

Comment: You're already getting the keys and using them to look up properties on the object. Where are you stuck? You seem to have the basics working above.

Comment: Crowder you are right when trying to get the solution for json in this form I Can

Here Is the Json

let responseObj = { 
           db_user: 'das1234',
           db_con:'ds67',
           db_password: 'ds345ty76',
           db_host: 'wdsa12',
           }
But If Json  is nested How I can proceed further?

Comment: Again: That's not JSON. That's just a JavaScript object initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You already have nearly all the pieces. You know how to get the property names (keys) from an object:

```
Object.keys(obj);
```

...and how to loop through them

```
.forEach(...)
```

The only missing piece is *recursion* and detecting that a property's value is another object. You can test taht by using `typeof`: `typeof something === "object"` tells us that `something` is an object (or `null`).

See comments:

```
var responseObj = {
    db_config: {
        db_user: 'das1234',
    },
    env_con: {
        db_con: 'ds67'
    },
    db_password: 'ds345ty76',
    db_host: 'wdsa12'
};

function decrypt(obj, key) {
    // Loop through this object's properties
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        // Get this property's value
        var value = obj[key];
        // If not falsy (null, empty string, etc.)...
        if (value) {
            // What is it?
            switch (typeof value) {
                case "object":
                    // It's an object, recurse
                    decrypt(value, key);
                    break;
                case "string":
                    // It's a string, decrypt
                    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key);
                    obj[key] = decipher.update(value, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
}

var res = decrypt(responseObj, key);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lets clarify first what JSON actually is. JSON is a textual,
>   language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML.

Source: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation/2904181#2904181)

That beeing said your question is about iterating the Object itself without calling for the keys. You are looking for this:

```
for (variable in object) {... }
```

Here is an example from MDN:

```
let obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (let prop in obj) {
  console.log("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

---

**Sidenote**

I don't know what you want to achieve with your JSON structure, but you could change your JSON from this:

```
var responseObj ={ 
           db_config:{
             db_user: 'das1234',
            },
           env_con:{
             db_con:'ds67'
           },
           db_password: 'ds345ty76',
           db_host: 'wdsa12'
          }
```

To this:

```
let responseObj = { 
           db_user: 'das1234',
           db_con:'ds67',
           db_password: 'ds345ty76',
           db_host: 'wdsa12',
           }
```

The new JSON would be flat and you don't have to worry about iterating through a nested object.

Example:

```
for (let prop in responseObj ) {
  console.log("o." + prop + " = " + responseObj [prop]);
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks But I have to iterate the  Json which I have mentioned because I got response in this form only.I tried to use this to iterate for decrypting the json value.

Comment: You could do another inside check within the loop like : `if ( typeof responseObj [prop] === 'object'` (be careful with typeof). Then do another `for (variable in object) {... }` (recursively). After that just return your desired values. Another option would be to flatten your given JSON before you iterate it. There are serveral options here on SO.